# Lenovo Ideapad Y480 can't reinstall windows?

Tags: windows-7, linux-mint, reinstall, gparted, lenovo-laptop

Alright, so here's the deal...

For a while, I wanted to mess with Linux. I don't know why, but I wanted to. So, what I did was use WUBI and install Ubuntu. Because of some unknown reason (Intel Rapid Start? Half the drivers being on a Lenovo-installed SSD [separate from the main hard drive]?) it wouldn't dual boot. So, I decided to use Linux Mint instead, and install it in a partition. Since Windows 7 Home Premium won't make partitions any more if you have a certain number already, I just shrank my system drive and left empty space for the installer to claim.

When I installed Mint, it worked, but left my Windows 7 installation unable to boot and eventually it corrupted. I tried to use a system repair disc I burned earlier but it didn't find the Windows installation, so I assume the partition corrupted.

I used this link:http://www.pcworld.com/article/248995/how_to_install_windows_7_without_the_disc.html
to try and reinstall Windows. What happened was that originally it said that the partition I was trying to reinstall from had been locked down by the OEM (Lenovo). So, I went into GParted, wiped EVERYTHING, and selected 'Construct new Boot record' or whatever that function is, and now the error is:

**"Setup was unable to create a new system partition or locate an existing system partition. See the setup log files for more information."**

Does anyone know how to see the log files? Can anyone help? This system is a month old but the warranty only covers hardware failures, and I would need to pay around USD$60 for them to fix it.

Please help. Any ideas? this is my main machine...

**Extra information: I have at my disposal:**

System Repair Disc (Burned myself)

Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit SP1 installation disk (burned from the pcworld links)

Gparted Live CD

Linux Mint 13 live cd

A system backup (from the morning before this catastrophe) made using the Windows Backup and Restore. I put it on an external drive...that should be safe for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wiped everything. That is why the instructions from PCworld don't work. You nuked your recovery partition (though to be honest, you might be able to get it back).

What you are looking to do is just have a fresh windows install. Just use the Windows 7 SP1 disk that you can, and install windows from there.

Comment: The thing is, I can't do a fresh install. When I'm in the Windows 7 SP1 Install disk, that error pops up. Does that make my problem clearer?

Comment: And which recovery partition were you speaking of, anyways? I made a backup to an external drive using Windows Backup, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: To the first comment, there should be no option to create a boot partition if the drive is blank. Are you sure you are doing a vanilla install? To the second, the parition that lenovo had on the drive

Comment: Ok, so my genius mother fixed my problem. You were the most helpful of the two answers I got, so i'm marking your answer correct :) What happened was basically Linux Mint screwed up my boot, so the computer wouldn't boot from the BIOS, but instead from GRUB, which, when I deleted the Mint partition, messed up everything. Second, in my BIOS, I put my SSD (which is much smaller) as the primary boot drive in the boot order, so Windows Installation thought that was the C drive. She switched that and now the installation is going. Crossing my fingers that the backup I made worked.

Answer (score 0):

Are you get a recovery cd froM where you buy a laptop?? Or did you burn The recovery files That are in the laptop to a cd??  Usually All the needs of the laptop is already available in the recovery that includes to re-install windows and drivers for you laptop hardwAres.

Comment: He destroyed his recovery partition.

Comment: I burned the recovery cd from windows. The laptop came with no disks.

Answer (score 0):

You just buy the recovery DVDs from Lenovo. The only thing you have to do is to tell them your machine number and pay $59.

They will post it to your address. Just recover from these discs and your laptop will be set to factory defaults.

Comment: My genius mother fixed this without paying $59 to lenovo. Please see the comment I wrote at the bottom of soandros' answer.